# How to copy data from sheet to another sheet on empty row

Tags: excel

Hy Experts, I have two worksheets. I am trying to copy the data from sheet "Input Sheet" to "Database" sheet by using this code.

[image]

[image]

```
Sub CopyInvoiceNo()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("Input Sheet")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Database")

    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("A3:J" & lastrow).Copy
    ws1.Range("B3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ws1.Activate

End Sub
```

this code is working very fine. But there is a problem. It overwrites the data when I press the button 2nd time.

The goal is that every time when I press "Paste Button" it should paste data after the first filled row. I tried but in vain. HOw could it be done. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't adjusting the target of the paste operation.

```
Sub CopyInvoiceNo()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("Input Sheet")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Database")

    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("A3:J" & lastrow).Copy
    ws1.Range("B" & rows.count).end(xlup).offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ws1.Activate

End Sub
```